# using bit-fields as representation for integers in c

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

In my C class we were given an assignment:

> Write an interactive program (standard input/output). Define the new type `set` using `typedef` which can hold a set of integers in the range 0-127. The data structure has to be as efficient as possible in terms of storage (hint: working with bits). Also you need to define 6 global variables A,B,C,D,E,F of type `set`. All operations on sets in the program will be on these 6 variables.
>
> This command `read_set A,5,6,7,4,5,4,-1` will read user's input of integers while `-1` means end of user's input. Other commands a user can use: `print_set A` - prints the set in increasing order, `union_set A,B,C` does union on 2 sets and saves the output in a third set, `intersect_set A,B,C` - determines the intersection of 2 sets and saves the output to a third set.

As far as I understand I need to use bit-fields. I could create a table of integers from 0-127. Then I could create the 6 variables `A,B,C,D,E,F` using `set` type definition and giving 128 bit-fields to each variable. Then if a user inputs `15` I would turn on the the bit which represents 15 in the data type. I'm really not sure if this is the way, because it's not clear to me how I would arrange bit-fields such that I can turn on exactly 15-th bit if I need to, I would need to convert somehow an integer to bit-field name... Also `print_set` prints the set in increasing order so how could I re-arrange bit-fields for this?

Really hope you have some ideas.

Comment: Research `CHAR_BIT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, each of the sets called A, B, C, D, E and F is represented by a couple of `unsigned long long` integers like this:

`typedef struct {
   unsigned long long high;
   unsigned long long low;
} Set;`

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types

This gives you 128 bits of data in a `Set` (64 bits for the high numbers 64 to 127, and 64 bits for the low numbers 0 to 63).

Then you just need to do some bit manipulation like this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_bits_manipulation.htm

For a number between 0 and 63, you'd shift 1 to the left x times and then set that bit on the "low" field.

For a number between 64 and 127, you'd shift 1 to the left x-64 times and then set that bit on the "high" field.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Using bitfields for this assignment will prove very cumbersome because of alignment issues, and you cannot define arrays of bitfields anyway. I would suggest using an array of bytes (`unsigned char`) and packing values into this array. A 7-bit value spanning at most 2 bytes.

The array for `count` values should be allocated with a size of `(count + 7) / 8` bytes. In order to conserve space, you can store small sets in an integer and larger sets using an allocated array.

The datatype would look like:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct set {
    size_t count;
    union {
        uintptr_t v;
        unsigned char *a;
    };
} set;
```

Here is how to extract the n-th value:

```
int get_7bits(const set *s, size_t n) {
    if (s == NULL || n >= s->count) {
        return -1;
    } else
    if (n < sizeof(uintptr_t) * CHAR_BIT / 7) {
        return (s->v >> (n * 7)) & 127;
    } else {
        size_t i = n / 7;
        int shift = n % 7;
        if (shift <= CHAR_BIT - 7) {
            /* value fits in one byte */
            return (s->a[i] >> shift) & 127;
        } else {
            /* value spans 2 bytes */
            return ((s->a[i] | (s->a[i + 1] << CHAR_BIT)) >> shift) & 127;
        }
    }
}
```

You can write the other access functions and complete your assignment.

Comment: What about `CHAR_BIT`?